# finding all possible values for the cardinality of a set s

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> The question and a solution from the Internet are shown below. I don't understand several aspects of the solution, so if someone could elaborate on those points, it would be nice:

1. Why does having an element $x$ such that $v_p(x) \ge 2$ imply that there are $\frac{e}{e+1}$ elements of $S$ divisible by $p$? There should clearly be $e$ elements of S divisible by p, corresponding to the divisors $p^i,1\leq i\leq e$, of $x$.
2. Similarly, why does the existence of a $y$ so that $v_p(y) = 1$ imply that $\frac{1}2$ of the elements of $S$ are divisible by $p$?
3. Why does $e= 1$?
4. Why does $|S|$ equal the number of divisors of any element of $S$? How does this show that $|S|$ has size equal to a power of $2$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4. Why does $|S|$ equal the number of divisors of any element of $S$?

Let $s \in S$, and let $D_s := \{n \in \Bbb N : n | s\}$ be the set of divisors of $s$. Then we can define the function $f_s : S \to D_s : x \mapsto \gcd(x,s)$. The condition on $S$ - that every $d \in D_s$ has a unique $t \in S$ with $f_s(t) = \gcd(t,s) = d$ - is exactly the requirement for the function $f_s$ to be a bijection. Thus $D_s$ and $S$ are bijective. I.e., $|D_s| = |S|$. And since $s$ was arbitrary, every element of $S$ has the exact same number of divisors.

> 2. Similarly, why does the existence of a $y$ so that $v_p(y) = 1$ imply that $\frac{1}2$ of the elements of $S$ are divisible by $p$?

Let $z = \frac yp$. Because $p^2$ does not divide $y, p$ does not divide $z$. If $d|y$, then either $p | d$ or not. If $p$ does not divide $d$, then $d|z$. If $p|d$, then $\frac pd \mid z$. So $D_y = D_z \cup pD_z$. $D_z$ and $pD_z$ (where $pD_z := \{pd: d \in D_z\}$) are disjoint (every element of $pD_z$ is divisible by $p$, while every element of $D_z$ is not), and the same size, so half the divisors of $D_y$ are in $D_z$ and the other half are in $pD_z$.

If $d \in D_z$, and $t\in S$ is the unique $t$ with $\gcd(t,y) = d$, then $p$ cannot divide $t$, since it divides $y$ but not $d$. But if $d \in pD_z$, then $p|d$ and so must divide $t$. Since every element of $S$ must fall into one of those two groups, they are also equally divided between those divisible by $p$ and those that are not.

> 1. Why does having an element $x$ such that $v_p(x) \ge 2$ imply that there are $\frac{e}{e+1}$ elements of $S$ divisible by $p$?

The wording here is ambiguous. What they are actually claiming is the *ratio* of the number of elements of $S$ that are divisible by $p$ to the total number of elements is $\frac e{e+1}$. This is because the ratio of divisors of $x$ that are divisible by $p$ to the total number of divisors is $\frac e{e+1}$. This is because each divisor divisible by $p$ is $p^id$ for some divisor $d$ not divisible by $p$, and there are $e$ possible values for $i$.

> 3. Why does $e= 1$?

Because the ratio of elements of $S$ divisible by $p$ to those that are not is both $\frac e{e+1}$ and $\frac 12$. Solving that equation gives $e = 1$.

> How does this show that $|S|$ has size equal to a power of $2$?

The consequence of the claim is that every member $s \in S$ is square-free. No square of any prime divides $s$. Suppose $s = p_1p_2\cdots p_n$. Then $s$ has $2^n$ divisors total (the number of subsets of $\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$). So $|S| = |D_s| = 2^n$.